# Using Callback for url schemes on Google Maps for iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps, callback, url-scheme

I'm trying to use the callback functionality of the URL schemes for Google Maps on iOS.

The way how to do that [is documented here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/ios-urlscheme#specify_a_callback_url).

However, I did not manage to get this to work. There is no additional symbol showing up as described in the documentation.

Is this actually still possible or has this feature been removed?

Independent of my application, I also tested this by pasting the URL scheme in the Safari browser, but it doesn't work there either.

It simply starts the Google Maps app but apparently ignores the callback parameters.

Edit:
This is the URL from the example of the documentation:

```
comgooglemaps-x-callback://?center=40.765819,-73.975866&zoom=14
   &x-success=sourceapp://?resume=true
   &x-source=SourceApp
```

The only difference would be that the success parameter gets the URL of the app you want to open when the user clicks on the callback button.

Comment: Could you paste your full url?

Comment: I edited the url.

Comment: Have you added the url scheme of your app as the callback parameter?

Comment: Yes I have, also I assume I could put any other url from another application too and it doesn't actually have to be the source app? I tested both of these ways, but nothing worked. The "source" parameter is supposed to be the text of the callback button, which is not appearing.

Comment: You can always manually test a url scheme for your app by pasting the link into Safari. If it doesn't open your app, there's something incorrect.

Comment: Opening my own app using Safari works, also I can open it from another application that I have made, but Google Maps wont use it as the callback url. I can barely find anything about this callback feature of google maps on the Internet, so I'm not sure if it actually still works.

Comment: Read another link that says since iOS 9, Apple has added a button on the top left corner that allows one to navigate back to the previous app if it's opened by a deep-link.

Comment: Thats true, it does add a button in the top left corner. But you cannot pass any parameters using that button or change its name sadly. I don't know if Google maybe removed the callback feature because of that.

Comment: Nor can you actually 'ensure' a callback.

Comment: I still haven't found a solution to this problem. Why would google document this feature if its not possible to actually use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your application's url scheme has been implemented correctly and that you're specifying a valid callback url (that directs back to your app).

Some links that might be useful:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html
http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html